# Can you have optional parameters with a limiting condition?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I want to create a function with two optional parameters, but you can only choose one of the two optional parameters.

For example:

```
 public void DoThing (int foo = 0, string bar = "test") {
    if (foo != 0)      // Do something with foo
    if (bar != "test") // Do something with bar
 }
```

However, if someone does `DoThing(1, "Hello World!");`, it will call both statuses and I don't want to allow them to use both.

Is it possible force them to fix this mistake before compiling the code?

Comment: Why not use overloads? Define one method that takes an `int` and one that takes a `string`?

Comment: Can you put that as an answer? I completely forgot about overloads! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not *overload* ?

```
public void DoThing (int foo) {
  // Do something with foo
}

public void DoThing (string bar) {
  // Do something with bar
}

public void DoThing (int foo, string bar) {
  // Do something with foo and bar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably create two overload of the method like

```
 public void DoThing (string bar, int foo = 0){
// code here
 }

 public void DoThing (int foo , string bar = "test"){
// code here
 }
```

Comment: optional parameters should be the last ones

Comment: @Badulake nice catch .. Thanks